# Windows From with C# - creating a List with the buttons in the parent form

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have `Windows Form` project based on `MDI`. A lot of my child forms need to do some changes (mostly on the  `ForeColor`) of the buttons from the parent form so I decided to make a `List<Button>` where I'll keep them and form where I gonna call them when needed. I tried this:

```
 List<Button> btn = new List<Button> { 
        btnButton1,
        btnButton2,
        .
        .
        };
```

> A field initializer can not reference the non-static field, method, or property...

I can't quite understand where the problem lies but still my main problem is how(if possible) to create such a `List` with the buttons from the main form. For now I intend to hardcode the name of each button into the `List`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should initialize list of buttons in the constructor of your form after InitializeComponent() call

Comment: Thanks, that was the key :)